# is there a general method for finding $a$ in a number of form $X=B^a*Y$ given $X$, and $B$

Tags: algorithms, prime-factorization

As an example

$X=17825792$ and $B=2$

I'm wanting to see if there's a method to find that $X$, in this example 17825792, has $B^a$ as a factor, in this example $2^{20}$.

A method that has a computation time less than linear is what I'm curious about.

Comment: You would consider iterated division brute force? (divide by 2 until you can't anymore)

Comment: I guess more accurately, more computationally complex. as the larger the $a$ is the more computation time there is. I'm wanting to see if there is an algorithm with a computation time that is less than linear.

Comment: There is no such method, as far as i know

Comment: Do you want computer programme

Comment: I can write one for such operations

Comment: Note that this the same as finding the [p-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order).

Comment: Why do you want an algorithm if you have computers for such work

Comment: The last page on [these slides](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~fvercaut/talks/pAdic.pdf) make it seem like there may be something better than brute force, but I don't know enough number theory to know precisely what.

Comment: im working on a possible set of numbers that work based on the idea of multiplying sets of numbers together and describing numbers based on repeating digits with a specific length. so if the set is the natural numbers, we'll call this product $L$, then $L$ would have $a$ come out infinite for any factors, and if i did 1 repeated $L$ times then there is no way of finding $a$ unless it's 2 or 5, in which case its 0. but if there was an algorithm other than just repeat divisions then i might be able to make sense of $a$.

Comment: Thank you Mark, p-adic order may hold some good info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an algorithm that goes faster than linear. Iteratively square the value of B until it does not divide X anymore and store the values in every step.

Then go backwards with that list and divide the X with that value, if that value divides X. And add a corresponding power of two to the resulting exponent. To better show this, it goes like this:

$2$ divides $X$, store $2$

$4$ divides $X$, store $4$

$16$ divides $X$, store $16$

$\vdots$

$2^{16}$ divides $X$, store $2^{16}$

$2^{32}$ does not divide $X$

set exponent to zero

$2^{16}$ divides $X$, divide $X$ by $2^{16}$, add $16$ to exponent

$2^{8}$ does not divide $X$ anymore

$2^{4}$ divides $X$, divide $X$ by $2^{4}$, add $4$ to exponent

$2^{2}$ does not divide $X$ anymore

$2$ does not divide $X$ anymore

return value of exponent, which is 20

Comment: This definitely has the details I was looking for, and even has the potential to be sped up more and more.

Comment: @DestinyRose I am afraid the only speeding up here is in using fast multiplication algorithms, or reducing memory complexity by slightly increasing computational complexity. But next time, this type of question is probably more suited for "Theoretical computer science stackexchange" or for "stackoverflow", which are sites dedicated among other things to optimizing algorithms.